# How to determine if theres a next page

Tags: pagination

I am new to wordpress development, just trying to convert my HTML into a WordPress theme, I started with Chris Coyer's blank theme.

```hmtl
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="next-posts">
        <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?>
    </div>
    <div class="prev-posts">
        <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I output the div only if there is a `next_posts_link()`. I need this as I will be using `<ul>` for my pagination. If I don't do that, I will get an empty bullet

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `get_previous_posts_link` and `get_next_posts_link`
to determine if they exists  like this:

```
$prev_link = get_previous_posts_link(__('&laquo; Older Entries'));
$next_link = get_next_posts_link(__('Newer Entries &raquo;'));
// as suggested in comments
if ($prev_link || $next_link) {
  echo '<ul class="navigation">';
  if ($prev_link){
    echo '<li>'.$prev_link .'</li>';
  }
  if ($next_link){
    echo '<li>'.$next_link .'</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Hope This Helps

Comment: Only problem there is you might potentially render an empty list, which will produce the invalid markup, and in effect will have the same issue the user has with the existing code..

Comment: @t31os, I guess I will do something like `if ($prev_link || $next_link) // output ul`

Comment: Yeah that would do it.. ;)

Comment: Updated the code

Comment: Thanks for the code, it's missing `echo '</ul>';` just before the last line btw.

Answer (score 14):

I wrote this up a while ago, but should still be valid:

http://www.ericmmartin.com/conditional-pagepost-navigation-links-in-wordpress-redux/

You can add the following function to your `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * If more than one page exists, return TRUE.
 */
function show_posts_nav() {
    global $wp_query;
    return ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1);
}
```

The update your code to:

```
<?php if (show_posts_nav()) : ?>
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
    <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

the best solution is checking `$wp_query->max_num_pages`, but you also can use:

```
<?php
if(paginate_links()) {
...
}
```

Comment: It's important to note that `$wp_query` doesn't appear to be available everywhere; for example, I tried to use it within a WooCommerce template override and the object didn't exist, so I had to call it from within `functions.php` instead by using Eric Martin's answer.

Comment: Of course, some case such as custom loops and maybe woocommerce need to be handled. In your case, you should check how to get The wp query of woocommerce or whatever query it generates.